# How to select import object name from another function

Tags: python, maya

EDIT: I have managed to solved the issue I wa having previously but instead of me creating another new question, this issue I have encountered are pretty much similar I guess?

As I am modifying some of the contents of this script that I am currently doingn, it will boot up this UI whenever user imports in a `.chan` object

Currently I am trying to edit the camera name such that when users selects the camera, it will inherits the name of the imported camera into its namespace.
Though I am not very sure, I think the `reader` function in the `customNodeTranslator` class is the one that reads the imported camera?

This is the error messgae:

```
# Error: global name 'cameraName' is not defined
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "/user_data/scripts/test/maya/plugins/chan.py", line 210, in readFileIn
#     self.importTheChan = ChanFileImporter(chanRotationOrder)
#   File "/user_data/scripts/test/maya/plugins/chan.py", line 286, in __init__
#     self.cameraName = cameraName
# NameError: global name 'cameraName' is not defined #
```

This is the original code:

```
class customNodeTranslator(OpenMayaMPx.MPxFileTranslator):
    ...    
    ...
    ...

    def reader(self, fileObject, optionString, accessMode):
        self.initialWindow()

        try:
            fullName = fileObject.fullName()
            print ">>> full Name is %s" %fullName

            #self.fileHandle = open(fullName,"r")
            camHandle = open(fullName,"r")
            camPath = os.path.basename(camHandle.name)
            camName = os.path.splitext(camPath)[0]
            print ">>> This is the name: %s" % camName

        except:
            sys.stderr.write( "Failed to read file information\n")
            raise

        return camName

class chanImport():
    """ importing chan camera from nuke """
    def __init__(self, rotation):
        self.rotation = rotationOrder
        # create the camera
        self.cameraName = cmds.camera(n=str(camName))
        self.cameraShape = self.cameraName[1]

        cmds.select(self.cameraShape)
        cmds.scale(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

The following code is the actual code itself before I modified:

```
 class customNodeTranslator(OpenMayaMPx.MPxFileTranslator):
    ...    
    ...
    ...
    def writer( self, fileObject, optionString, accessMode ):
        try:
            fullName = fileObject.fullName()
            fileHandle = open(fullName,"w")

            selectList = OpenMaya.MSelectionList()

            OpenMaya.MGlobal.getActiveSelectionList(selectList)
            node = OpenMaya.MObject()
            depFn = OpenMaya.MFnDependencyNode()
            path = OpenMaya.MDagPath()
            iterator = OpenMaya.MItSelectionList(selectList)

                animationTime = OpenMayaAnim.MAnimControl()
    class ChanFileImporter():
        def __init__(self, rotationOrder):
            self.rotationOrder = rotationOrder
            # create the camera
            self.cameraName = cmds.camera()
            self.cameraShape = self.cameraName[1]
            cmds.select(self.cameraShape)
            cmds.scale(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
```

Comment: Can you share the full and exact error message you're getting? You may need to take out the exception handling to be sure you don't mask the error.

Comment: @mhlester Sorry for the late reply. I have just added in the error message which is as follows. It seems that global variables may not be a good idea. Are there any ways that I can try modifying it just so to grab the name of the camera?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't passing the camName to the importer class. In fact you're not invoking the importer class at all in the sample above.

If you modify chanImport so it takes the name you want:

```
class chanImport(object):
    """ importing chan camera from nuke """
     def __init__(self, camName):
        self.desiredCameraName = camName
        self.cameraName = None
        self.cameraShape = None

     def create_camera(self):
        self.cameraName, self.cameraShape =  cmds.camera(n=str(camName))
        cmds.select(self.cameraShape)
        cmds.scale(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)
        return self.cameraName
```

You should be able to invoke it inside your reader function:

```
def reader(self, fileObject, optionString, accessMode):
    self.initialWindow()

    try:
        fullName = fileObject.fullName()
        print ">>> full Name is %s" %fullName
        camHandle = open(fullName,"r")
        camPath = os.path.basename(camHandle.name)
        camName = os.path.splitext(camPath)[0]
        print ">>> This is the name: %s" % camName
        importer = chanImport(camName)
        actual_cam_name =   importer.create_camera()
        print ">>> created " + actual_cam_name
        return actual_cam_name 
    except:
        sys.stderr.write( "Failed to read file information\n")
        raise
```

Comment: I tried using your code, and as I did my import, I am getting the following error: `TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'unicode'` in the line - `importer = ChanFileImporter(camName)`. But even so, as I still needs the `rotationOrder` arguement. Tried adding into the __init__ functiion, I am getting the error `# TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given) // `

Comment: I actually have 2 questions. First, pardon me but I am not seeing the 'link' between the reader function and the ones withing ChanImport. `cameraName` was returned in the `reader` however I thought I would see the same variable to be read in the ChanImport class, no? Secondly, will it be a good idea if I set the `__init__` function to remain as it is (reading in the rotationOrder) while the `createCamera` would looks like `def create_camera(self, camName):`? I asked as I realised that there is another line seeking for the rotation values

Comment: You can add the rotation argument to the __init__ of chanImport and store it, the way I did with camName.   You can then apply it in create_camera(); `takes exactly....` means you're passing an argument into a function which is not present in the definition. 

You can simplify this by not making a class out of chanImport: since it only gets used once you lose nothing by folding the functionality into the reader directly.

Comment: Hmm... I will try that out otherwise I may need to do some editing to the rotationOrder that the other line is trying to call it from. By the way, I am just curious, in this scenario of mine, wouldn't using `global` variable be ideal since I am trying to recall the camera name across functions or class?

Comment: You already know the info, so it's better to pass it in directly. Globals are a big source of problems, since you can never be sure what state they are in just by stepping through the code

Comment: Just one last question, any ideas why does the camera creation commands keep adding a numerical/increase the suffix - 1,2,3 etc.? I tried a simple example by giving the camName as `pop123` but whenever I run the command `cameraName =  cmds.camera(n=str(camName))`, my camera is either named as `pop1` or `pop124`. Same applies when I only named my camera alphabetically.

Comment: Maya always does that when there is already another object with the same name.  All  maya object names must be unique so calling the same creation command with the same name will create a ratcheting number

Comment: Okay... So there's no way to get rid of it unless I introduced another renaming command?

Comment: If it's happening, your scene is filling up with cameras. You'll never get two objects at the same level with the same name

Comment: I understand. Just that when I was using the Create >> Camera s from the menu and renaming it afterwards, I had thought it can be done since it allows me to name the camera as I want despite being in a new fresh empty scene. Thus i had think that it is also achievable through using coding